# A No Sensa Test Question with Mediterranean Flavor

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Which of the three options fit in the central Octagon which is common to the two diagonals, one vertical and one horizontal row? Separately, each diagonal row (Brown and Red boxes), the horizontal row (Blue boxes) and the vertical row (Black boxes) creates a pattern when combined with the Octagon content.

There is a common theme here.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll go with

> Octagon B.

That one creates a

> Greek capital letter along all the lines.

Like so:

> | Black:  (alpha)
>  - Blue:  (theta)
>  / Red:  (xi)
>  \ Brown:  (epsilon)

This fits in nicely with the Mediterranean clue in the title too.

Comment: gung jnf hygen snfg. Jbhyq lbh unir thrffrq vg jvgubhg gur gvgyr?

Comment: I think so, the horizontal line left very few options. But who knows?